# The L ' Hopitals rule serves for some kinds of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was with this doubt whether the L 'Hopitals rule only serve for $\sin x$, $\arccos x$, $\tan x$, $\ln x$, $e^x$, these crazy trigonometrys there, because on the internet I just found explanations of the theorem of L'Hopital just in these examples. Could enlighten me if there is the possibility of using this theorem for any expression, in terms which seem must have for apply L'Hopital:

Ratio of two functions: $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, when the limits are in indetermination, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differentiable and $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $x \to c$ (except possibly at $c$) and using polynomial equations of varying degrees, with or without root, in simple limits.

Please, the more examples to post better!

Comment: Your description in the second paragraph is correct, as long as you interpret "limits are in indetermination" to mean that "either both $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)=0$ or both $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$" and interpret "$g'(x)\ne0$ for $x\to c$" to mean that "there is a punctured neighborhood of $c$ in which $g'(x)\ne0$".

Comment: "I was with this doubt whether the L 'Hopitals rule only serve for sinx, arccosx, tanx, lnx, ex, these crazy trigonometrys there, because on the internet I just found explanations of the theorem of L'Hopital just in these examples."  I honestly don't understand when people write that they couldn't find out Y about X using the internet, when in fact if you just google X you'll get to Y on the first page of hits.  In this case if you google L'Hopital's Rule, the first hit is the wikipedia article, which contains an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital's rule does work for any two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, to find the limit
$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)},$$ as long as $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ and both functions are differentiable. If $f$ and $g$ are in fact continuously differentiable (meaning that their derivatives are also continuous) and $g'(x) \ne 0$, there is a relatively easy proof of this:
$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x)-0}{g(x)-0} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x) - f(c)}{g(x) - g(c)},$$
since $f(c) = g(c) = 0$, and
$$ \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x) - f(c)}{g(x) - g(c)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {\frac{f(x) - f(c)} {x-c}}{\frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x-c}} = \frac {\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)} {x-c}}{\lim_{x \to c} \frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x-c}} = \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)},$$
using properites of limits and the definition of derivative.
For a proof of the more general case, see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Proof_of_l.27H.C3.B4pital.27s_rule).

Comment: L'Hospital can also be used when $f(x)\to\infty$ and $g(x)\to\infty$.

Comment: @robjohn and you don't even need $f(x) \to \infty$....